How do I make JTable respect size of TableColumn?
How do I make JTable respect the default size of TableColumn that I specify? The column should still be shrinkable/extendable for the user, but the default should match the value I set
Here's a small demo that reproduces what I consider a problem
Instead of 10 pixels, the table sets the size of the column to 225 pixels. Even calling setWidth() instead of setPreferredWidth() has no effect
package demos.table;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SOTableDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple JTable Demo");

            Object[][] data = {
                    {"John", 25},
                    {"Doe", 30},
                    {"Jane", 22},
                    {"Smith", 28}
            };
            Object[] columns = {"Name", "Age"};

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);

            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(10); // I want JTable to respect that

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(scrollPane);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

Here's the code that calculates that nonsensical 225. I have no idea why JTable does that (or, frankly, what it does), but I don't like it at all. I want it to stop it
// javax.swing.JTable#adjustSizes(long, javax.swing.JTable.Resizable2, boolean)

                double f = (double)(target - totalLowerBound)/(totalUpperBound - totalLowerBound);
                newSize = (int)Math.round(lowerBound+f*(upperBound - lowerBound));

How can I control the default size of a TableColumn?

You can try controlling the column size by specifying the preferred sizes for the other columns and also the scroll pane.

@prasad_ I only care about that column

Then try using other methods, setMaxWidth or sizeWidthToFit.

@prasad_ setMaxWidth() makes it impossible for the user to widen the column. sizeWidthToFit() is ignored by JTable at all (at least, in my demo)

Have you looked at JTables method setAutoResizeMode - AUTO_RESIZE_OFF, AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN, AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS, AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN, AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS

I modified the posted code to get the width of column 0 and set the total width of the scrollable viewport size  It appears that you must add all the column widths to get the total width.
Here's the modified code.
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SOTableDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple JTable Demo");

            Object[][] data = {
                    {"John", 25},
                    {"Doe", 30},
                    {"Jane", 22},
                    {"Smith", 28}
            };
            Object[] columns = {"Name", "Age"};

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);

            int col0Width =  table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getPreferredWidth();
            // I want JTable to respect that
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(10);
            Dimension d = table.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
            d.width = col0Width + 10;
//            System.out.println(d);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(d);
            frame.add(scrollPane);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}


Thank you, but unfortunately you change the size of the entire table container and consequently window. I want them to stay as is. It's the default width of the column that I want to set

@Heneh: Okay, let's try this.  The sum of the width of the columns must equal the width of the table.  The default is 450 pixels.  If you want the age to be 10 pixels, the name must be 440 pixels.

Whatever, I just want to make the column 10 pixels wide without manually setting other sizes (like you do)

@Heneh: Sorry, but that's not how Swing works.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the How to Use Tables section.

The following seems to work for me:
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SOTableDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple JTable Demo");

            Object[][] data = {
                    {"John", 25},
                    {"Doe", 30},
                    {"Jane", 22},
                    {"Smith", 28}
            };
            Object[] columns = {"Name", "Age"};

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);

            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(30);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(1000);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.add(scrollPane);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

Not sure why you need to set the max width as well.
The default for the max width is Integer.MAX_VALUE. So I'm guessing that setting the value smaller results in a relatively small max width compared to the other column so its size isn't affected when the automatic sizing methods of the table are invoked.
Didn't test to see if this works with other resize modes.
